Find total number of days from different period of times for each group in R
I need to find the number of days for each Group from multiple projects' periods. If there are time overlap between projects, the days should not be counted more than once in the total.
df<- structure(list(Group.ID = c("BQNX", "BQNX", "CLXW", "CLXW", "CLXW", 
"CLXW", "CLXW", "CLXW", "CLXW", "CXJR", "CXJR", "CXJR", "DMM", 
"DMM", "DMM"), Project.ID = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 3), Start.Date = structure(c(19655, 19655, 19653, 19687, 
19694, 19653, 19687, 19694, 19653, 19653, 19653, 19653, 19687, 
19651, 19687), class = "Date"), End.Date = structure(c(19675, 
19682, 19687, 19693, 19733, 19686, 19693, 19733, 19686, 19655, 
19690, 19690, 19693, 19686, 19693), class = "Date"), Days = structure(c(20, 
27, 34, 6, 39, 33, 6, 39, 33, 2, 37, 37, 6, 35, 6), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
   


I want to find the total number of days that each Group.ID has from multiple projects. If two projects have some time overlap, the day should be counted once only. For example,

BQNX's Project 1 and 2 have some overlap so total days for BQNX is only 27 days.


CXJR has 3 projects with the same start dates so total days is only 37 days.


CLXW is more complicated: Projects 1,4 and 7 has the same start dates so total length is 34 days. Projects 2 & 5 have the same start and end dates and start dates is right after project 1's end date so total length is now 34 + 6 = 40 days. Then project 3 and 6 have the same dates and start dates is right after project 2's end date so total length is now 40 + 39 = 79 days

The final data frame I want is just the total number of consecutive days for each Group.ID. Sth like this:
data.frame(Group.ID = c("BQNX", "CLXW", "CXJR"), Consecutive.Days = c(27,37,79) )

Is there any way to achieve this? I am struggling to calculate the total number of days due to variations in dates and projects of each groups. Thank you

Thank you. I found the answer from this post. The number of days should also include the start dates and end dates. Counting distinct days from multiple periods of each group turns out to be the easiest way
data <- df<- structure(list(Group.ID = c("BQNX", "BQNX", "CLXW", "CLXW", "CLXW", 
                                         "CLXW", "CLXW", "CLXW", "CLXW", "CXJR", "CXJR", "CXJR", "DMM", 
                                         "DMM", "DMM"), Project.ID = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
                                                                       3, 1, 2, 3), Start.Date = structure(c(19655, 19655, 19653, 19687, 
                                                                                                             19694, 19653, 19687, 19694, 19653, 19653, 19653, 19653, 19687, 
                                                                                                             19651, 19687), class = "Date"), End.Date = structure(c(19675, 
                                                                                                                                                                    19682, 19687, 19693, 19733, 19686, 19693, 19733, 19686, 19655, 
                                                                                                                                                                    19690, 19690, 19693, 19686, 19693), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    15L), class = "data.frame")
data
 Group.ID Project.ID Start.Date   End.Date
1      BQNX          1 2023-10-25 2023-11-14
2      BQNX          2 2023-10-25 2023-11-21
3      CLXW          1 2023-10-23 2023-11-26
4      CLXW          2 2023-11-26 2023-12-02
5      CLXW          3 2023-12-03 2024-01-11
6      CLXW          4 2023-10-23 2023-11-25
7      CLXW          5 2023-11-26 2023-12-02
8      CLXW          6 2023-12-03 2024-01-11
9      CLXW          7 2023-10-23 2023-11-25
10     CXJR          1 2023-10-23 2023-10-25
11     CXJR          2 2023-10-23 2023-11-29
12     CXJR          3 2023-10-23 2023-11-29
13      DMM          1 2023-11-26 2023-12-02
14      DMM          2 2023-10-21 2023-11-25
15      DMM          3 2023-11-26 2023-12-02
data2 <- data %>% rowwise() %>% 
    do(tibble(Group.ID = .$Group.ID, 
              Date = seq(.$Start.Date, .$End.Date, by = 1))) %>%
    distinct() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    count(Group.ID)
data2

  Group.ID     n
  <chr>    <int>
1 BQNX        28
2 CLXW        81
3 CXJR        38
4 DMM         43


Maybe something like this works for you.
Edit: First arranging by Start.Date and regrouping should give the right result even with gaps.
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(Group.ID, Start.Date) %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(Start.Date > lag(End.Date, def=first(Start.Date))), .by = Group.ID) %>%
  summarize(inter = sum(max(End.Date) - min(Start.Date)), .by = c(Group.ID, grp)) %>% 
  summarize(Consecutive.Days = sum(inter), .by = Group.ID)
  Group.ID Consecutive.Days
1     BQNX          27 days
2     CLXW          79 days
3     CXJR          37 days
4      DMM          41 days


Thank you but this won't work when Group ID has projects with no time overlap.
